# Border on hidden ranges show when VBA is used to modify cell formats (including borders) across a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, border, hidden

I develop models for clients in Excel, and often times need to adjust the color schemes of a single model to match those of a client's logo/brand. I decided to construct a tool in VBA to adjust the color scheme across a workbook according to a set color pallet. When I run the VBA tool, it adjusts existing color formats to the new color scheme. Some ranges are hidden in the workbook. I adjust the format for hidden ranges as well, as settings could be changed unhide the cells. The VBA tool loops through each cell in a sheet (up to the last used row and column) and adjusts formatting colors.

The problem arises with the borders. If we take an example, assume cell $B$2 is hidden and has a border. As the tool loops through the cells it will arrive at $B$1 and detect a bottom border, intended for $B$2, and change the color. $B$1 is not hidden in the sheet, and I think that the border format change causes Excel to "think" that $B$1 has been assigned a border.  Thus when the macro is finished, the bottom border on $B$1 will show as a line (when I need it to remain hidden).

If I understand things correctly, somehow Excel "knows" if a border is intended for a specific cell because it hides the border when the cell is hidden. Does anyone know what property this is? If I knew, I could check the property, and only apply the border change when it is of a correct value. Other ideas?

I provide an abridged version of the code below. Many thanks for any support you can provide!

```
Sub SwitchSheetColorScheme(ByVal strShtName as String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rngSheetRange = GetActiveShtRange(strShtName) 'reduces sheet range to in-use range
Set rngNewColors = Range("cntrl_new_colorCode_rng") 'range of new color numeric values
Set rngOldColors = Range("cntrl_old_colorCode_rng") 'range of old color numeric values
  
For i = 1 To rngNewColors.Count
    For Each cell In rngSheetRange
        Dim ColorObjects As New Collection
            ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders.Item(xlEdgeTop)
            ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders.Item(xlEdgeBottom)
                
        Dim attrib As String
        attrib = "Color"
            
          
            For x = 1 To ColorObjects.Count
                If CallByName(ColorObjects(x), attrib, VbGet) = rngOldColors(i, 1) Then
                    ColorObjects(x).Color = rngNewColors(i, 1)
                End If
            Next
     
        
        Set ColorObjects = Nothing

    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly but try checking first if the cell is hidden or not, and adapt the code in both cases. Another option would be looping trough visible cells only and then looping through hidden cells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to reformat both formatted hidden and formatted visible cells, but, after the code is run, visible cells without a visible border will get a visible border when they are adjacent to hidden cells with borders (the adjacent cell's borders are also hidden). I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure the problem would persist even if I looped through hidden then unhidden cells, or if I checked if the cells were hidden or not.

Comment: I have added a picture to the post to show the problem

Comment: I would check for surrounding hidden cells when handling the visible cells - if e.g. there is a hidden cell to the right don't touch borderXlEdgeRight of the visible cell

Comment: Thanks for the response/idea. That will be tricky because I will have to have someway of anticipating (in an automated way) if the boarder belongs to the cell or the adjacent hidden cell. If the border belongs to the cell, I will want it not to be hidden, but otherwise hidden with the adjacent cell. I maybe be able to set up the conditions so this will work, but I'll have to think on it. I'll come back to you if I find a way to make it work. Thanks again for the idea.

Comment: I still have not been able to find a solution that works. If anyone watches this super basic youtube video https://youtu.be/_Bje4-q5C2U (starting at 00:45 until 1:37), You will see that somehow, Excel "knows" to which cell the border belongs. I have checked all border properties, including ".parent". There must be a way to understand how Excel knows this and use it in a script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally got it figured out. At least I have a solution that seems to work. Where I went wrong was that I was focusing on the borders themselves in the hopes of finding a property that indicates to which cell the border belongs: `Range("SomeRangeWithBorders").Borders.Item(xlEdgeTop).[SomeSpecialProperty]`. But what I have found is that the Range property `Borders.LineStyle(i)` where `i` is an integer between 1 and 6 (four outside borders, and two diagonal borders), will return the value -4142 when there is not a border assigned to the cell. This -4142 value persists even in cases where adjacent cells have a shared border with the cell and the border was was assigned to the adjacent cell. So I first check if the `.Borders.LineStyle(i)` property is equal to -4142, and if its not, then I change the border format.

So, in summary, I the line reading:

```
ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
```

Would be replaced with:

```
If cell.Borders(1).LineStyle <> -4142 Then
     ColorObjects.Add cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
End If
```

I hope this is helpful to that one special person who runs into a similar problem!